# How to hide the ticks for first child and last child in n3-charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I am using n3-charts which uses the line-chart.min.js and d3.v2.js plugin.I wanted to hide the x axis 0th tick value and last child tick value. How to do in the following image.[image]

Kindly, someone help me to resolve this issue, I don't want the APR11 and the last tick value which will change dynamically.

```
app.directive('barChart', [
                       function () {

                           return {
                               restrict: 'EA',
                               template: '<linechart data="data" options="options" width="550" height="291"></linechart>',
                               scope: {
                                   range: '=',
                               },
                               link: function(scope, elements, attrs){
                                   scope.$watch("range", function () { 
                                   var values = scope.range;
                                   scope.data = values;
                                       scope.options = {
                                           yaxis  : {name: "Calories",labelalign:"-135"},
                                           stacks: [{axis: "y", series: ["firstVal", "secondVal", 'thirdVal']}],
                                           fonts:  {family: 'serif', size: '14px'},
                                           axes: {
                                               x: {key: 'x', type: 'date',labelFunction: function(x) { return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(x));}},
                                               y: {key :'y',type: 'linear',min:0}
                                           },
                                           transition: {ease: 'elastic', duration: 1000, delay: 100},
                                           series: [
                                               {id: 'secondVal', y: 'secondVal', axis: 'y', color: "#b3d660", type: 'column', drawDots: true, dotSize: 4, label: 'Labe1'},
                                               {id: 'firstVal', y: 'firstVal', axis: 'y', color: "#ff8669", thickness: '2px', type: 'column', label: 'Label2'},
                                               {id: 'thirdVal', y: 'thirdVal', axis: 'y', color: "#52c4dc", type: 'column', dotSize: 2, label: 'Label3'}
                                           ],
                                           lineMode: 'linear',
                                           tension: 0.2,
                                           tooltip: {
                                               mode: 'scrubber', formatter: function (x, y, series) {
                                                   return series.label + ', ' + Math.round(y);
                                               }
                                           },
                                           drawLegend: true,
                                           drawDots: true,
                                           columnsHGap: 5
                                       }
                                   });
                               }

                           };}]);
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Answer (score 1):

For n3-charts v2, you can define a tickFormat function for each axis.

add a function called tickFormat to scope.options.axes.x that goes something like this:

```
tickFormat: function(value, index){
    var firstOrLast = (index === 0) || (index === scope.values.length-1);
    return firstOrLast ? "" : value;
}
```

Not sure about n3-charts v1, but I see that you already have a function called labelFunction in scope.options.axes.x. You could do something similar to the above code, but you would just check if your parameter 'x' matches your first or last value in scope.values.